# getLocation on dynamically created JButtons in java

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jbutton, null-layout-manager

OK so i dynamically made a line of J Buttons on a J Panel with a null layout using this code:

```
int Y = 100;
int X = 100;
for(x=1, x<=20, x++){
    button = new JButton(x);
    button.setLayout(null);
    button.setSize(100, 100);
    button.setLocation(X,Y);
    button.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(button); 

    X += 100;

    //action listener
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //should print out the location of the button that was clicked
            System.out.println(button.getLocation());
        }
    });
}
```

and i when i press on of does button i want it to print its location on the panel but instead it prints out the location of the last button that was added every time, please help.

take note that i am a very new to programming

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `button` variable is being redefined everytime you run the loop, so when you finally call your `actionPerformed` method, you are reading the data of the last button. The loop finished before any event happened and saved the reference of the last button created in the `button` variable.

You need to reference the `button` from the event object, because it contains a reference to the button that is the source of the event:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //should print out the location of the button that was clicked
        System.out.println( ((JButton)e.getSource()).getLocation() );
    }
});
```

The `addActionListener` method is called 20 times, but the `actionPerformed` method is called asynchronously and only when an action event (ex: button click) happens. The ActionEvent object contains information about the event, which includes the source of the event, which is your button.